# How do I make something blink when a variable changes with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular and I have some css like this:

```
.heartbeat
{
     transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}

.heartbeat-active
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

On a regular interval a property on scope is updated. How can I make this transition run once, whenever the property changes?

I have looked at ngAnimation and addClass, but have not been able to figure out how to stich that together declaratively. If that's even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by gnom1gnoms answer and this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/xZptsb-NYc4/rKAxJ3dQhbMJ, what I ended up doing was this:

```
app.directive('highlightOnChange', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('highlightOnChange', function(val) {
        var el = $(element);
        el.removeClass('heartbeat');
        _.defer(function() {
          el.addClass('heartbeat')
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

That is, creating a directive observes the property. I can then use it like this:

```
<div highlight-on-change="{{value}}"></div>
```

And don't need to have a reference to the element from $scope.

Answer (score 0):

Simply watch the property that you mentioned and addClass heartbeat-active when the watch is triggered

```
$scope.$watch('yourProperty', function(new, old) {
  if(new != old)
     $scope.yourElement.addClass(".heartbeat-active");
});
```

I assume that the element you want to blink is referenced inside the scope.
Second thing - you should add some initial value of opacity to the heartbeat class.

Comment: -1 very unclean. This should not be a `$watch`, but an angular animation. Also a `$watch` should never fire unless `new` and `old` are different, so you don't need the if statement. Also also, never name a variable `new` its a reserved word by javascript.

Comment: @Fresheyeball thanks for the comment. What is the difference between my directive and an angular animation, that you mention? Would an animatin be better suited?

Comment: An [angular animation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.$animator) is its own animal and part of angular's built in infrastructure to manage these kinds of things. You shouldn't have to use a `$watch` for animation, it should be something you can declare at the HTML level.